# when i execute query delete min field, message appears: "MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause "

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i want to delete a product with the min "sale_quantity" in table product.

and This is my query:

```
use warehousingaquarium;
delete from product
where product.sale_quantity = (select min(p2.sale_quantity) 
                from product p2);
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

It gives me the following error:

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'product' for update in FROM clause

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0fWA.png)

Answer (score 2):

One way to get around this problem would be to phrase your delete as a join:

```sql
DELETE p1
FROM product p1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(sale_quantity) AS min_sale_quantity
    FROM product
) p2
    ON p2.min_sale_quantity = p1.sale_quantity;
```

Answer (score 1):

For updating and deleting from such clause where subquery contains the same table that you are deleting from, a temporary table is required so that you don't delete the data where you are selecting from.
In order to make  your query work, you need to introduce a temp table:

USE,

```
delete from product
where product.sale_quantity = (select min(p2.sale_quantity) 
                from (Select * from product) p2);
```